# Cleaning a text-mail after/before a procmail process in order to have a print of that mail

Tags: linux, shell, procmail

I've to clean some mails in order to print only their body with procmail :

```
:0: # printing mail with bb in the subject to bbprinter
* ^Subject:.*bb
| lpr -Pbbprinter
```

How should I make that ?

Any idea-help welcome

Comment: The second colon is superfluous and would cause a `Could not determine implicit lockfile` error message.  See http://partmaps.org/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#locking

Answer (score 1):

Your question is ill-defined in a number of ways.  What do you mean by "clean"?  What do you mean by "body"?

If you mean, how can I send just the RFC5322 body, not the headers, to the printer, that's easy:

```
:0b
* ^Subject:.*bb
| lpr -Pbbprinter
```

Notice the `b` flag there after the `:0`, which restricts the scope of the action to just the body.

But with MIME, you frequently don't actually want the RFC5322 body (that is, everything after the last header line) but rather only one part out of a MIME multipart message.  You would need to come up with some analysis of which part to extract, but if you have that, it's still easy:

```
:0
* ^Subject:.*bb
| parse-out-preferred-mime-body-part | lpr -Pbbprinter
```

(We don't use `:0b` here because a proper MIME parser needs access to the top-level RFC5322 headers, too.)

If by "clean" you mean something else, or in addition, you will have to clarify your question, but the general idea is something like

```
:0
* ^Subject:.*bb
| cleanupbody | lpr -Pbbprinter
```

where `cleanupbody` could perform whatever you mean by "cleanup" (blot out curse words? Fix common typos? More or less the same thing?)

Finally, just to wrap up, you can basically pipe to a shell script of any complexity (although by the time it spans more than a few lines, you are probably better off moving all or parts of it to a separate script, perhaps with a test suite of its own).

```
:0
* ^Subject:.*bb
| parse-out-preferred-mime-body-part | \
  sed -e 's/grammer/grammar/g' -e 's/seperate/separate/g' \
      -e 's/definately/definitely/g' | \
  lpr -Pbbprinter
```